# sorting regex find mongodb mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

The regex find in mongodb works more like a filter than a search. is there anyway to sort the results based on the regex?

P.S: I know MongoDB has Full text search but I looking for a solution that gives result even when partial word is typed.

Also, I know that solutions like connecting MongoDB with Elastic Search exist but I'm looking for a simple solution which does not require hosting another service.

Also, performance is not an issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "sort the results based on the regex"? Updating your question to include a specific example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

$regex is use only for field type String.It doesn't work with other types

Let Consider small Example for Playing with regex operator

//Let take User Model as below

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    Name:String,
    Age:Number,
    Sex:Boolean,
    EmailID:String,
    PhoneNumber:String,
    Description:String,
    created_at:Date,
    updated_at:Date
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserSchema', UserSchema);
```

Your mongodb query for multi search with $regex operator and $options for multi-search will be like below

```
var toSearch = req.body.searchvalue;
var query = {
    $or:[
        {
            "Name":{
                $regex:toSearch,
                $options:"i"       //it will match both upper case and lower case
            }
        },
        {
            "EmailID":{
                $regex:toSearch,
                $options:"i"       //it will match both upper case and lower case
            }
        },
        {
            "PhoneNumber":{
                $regex:toSearch,
                $options:"i"       //it will match both upper case and lower case
            }
        },{
            "Description":{
                $regex:toSearch,
                $options:"i"       //it will match both upper case and lower case
            }
        }
    ]
}
//Important point to remember  we cannot use $regex for age,sex,created_at,updated_at because this field are not String


UserSchema.find(query).toArray(function (err,SearchData) {
    if(!err){
        //perform your operations
    }
}) ;
```

Might this may help you and it is best to create search engine in mongodb. it is next effective to Elastic Search which is no.1